# PHP-CRUD-API - Is it possible to restrict the max number of rows in a table?

Tags: php, api

I'm using [PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api) and it is working great.
I want to create a rule to restrict the maximum possible rows that a user can insert in a given table.
Is it possible to do that with an authorization rule?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
'authorization.recordHandler' => function ($operation, $tableName) {
   if($operation == 'insert' && $tableName == 'table1') {
     
     // The magic probably happens here.         
     return (current number of rows in table1 is less than, say, 100);
      
   }
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: Share part of your code, what have you tried so far and community here could help you.

Comment: Feel free to open an [issue on Github](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/issues) to ask for help. Kind regards, Maurits

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a rule to restrict the maximum possible rows that a user can insert in a given table.
> Is it possible to do that with an authorization rule?

Not with the authorization middleware in that project, but you may use the beforeHandler of the customization middleware, as that has access to the request body.

Alternatively, you may write your own middleware that does this.

NB: I'm the maintainer of PHP-CRUD-API

Comment: Thanks, I have read the [customization-handlers](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api#customization-handlers) section in the project's readme file. Where can I find info about those functions? like pupose, return type, parameters roll and strucre (objects structre)? And also: How get I get the current number of rows in a given table? Should I do that by myself using pain php+pdo, or the api can help me?

Comment: By the way, currently, I use Mysql triggers to solve my problem.

Comment: @Miro IMHO constraints should go in the database, not in the API code, so I agree with your approach. You can do all kinds of magic in the middleware and in the handlers. There are examples of the middleware in the src and examples of the handlers in the tests and in the github issues.